# How and in what file I set cache-control max age on my server reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, build, cache-control

I'm new in reactJs. 
After building my application and testing with google pagespeed , it's mentionned that cache-control must be configured on some files.

How and in what file I can configured it ? 
In my webpack config, I make cache = true;

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with React.js. What server language and framework are you using?

Comment: ah okay, I just build (npm run-script build) the app on a  windows server. After I use the command serve -s . Wichfile in my server should I configure ?